# Add computations in between layers in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am splitting Keras CNN model M into two parts: feature extractor E(X) and predictor P(Y). Extractor computes the feature maps from image, predictor makes prediction from these feature maps. This is basically splitting the network by the last conv layer.

Now, I need to add some operations **after E** and **before P**: `E' = f(E(X))`, `P'=P(g(Y))`.

So far I've been using `K.function()` to split the model into two functions.

```
E = K.function(M.inputs, [M.get_layer('last_conv').output])
P = K.function([M.get_layer('following_layer').input], M.outputs)
```

How can I construct functions that will compute f(E(X)) and P(g(Y))?

Another question: **can I do this using Model class?** f(E(X)) seems easy, but what about P(g(Y))? The problem is equivalent to inserting some layers to the pretrained model, and then splitting it into two functions.